# How to implement Date event listener for whenever a certain time has been reached?

Tags: javascript, date, event-listener

I have a `LiveDate` time which displays the current live date and it's got a property `_date` which holds a `Date` object with the current UTC date.

What would be the best method to set some listeners so that if a certain timestamp has been reached, a function is executed?

Would it be practical performance wise to for example use a `setTimeout()` that would check every 50ms for all of the set callbacks and run whichever matches the current time?

I would like to know what method would be the best to implement such a feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution must be too obvious ;)

You compute the time left until that timestamp, and set a Timeout accordingly. Perfectly efficient and accurate:

```
dT = targetTime - new Date()
setTimeout(alert, dT, "time's up!")
```

Comment: Is the accuracy of the delay not compromised by the extra delay the browser introduces when waiting for CPU time (for example by browser on other tabs)?

Comment: No. You seem to misunderstand how setTimeout works. It relies on the OS to remind the browser to run the callback at the specified time, regardless of how busy the CPU has been in the meantime.

Comment: Of course, if the JavaScript thread is busy when the time comes, the callback will have to wait. But that's unavoidable.